# Activity Feeds - Follow/Unfollow button greyed out?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

My question is, aside from the 'Activity Feeds Configuration' in the setting area of the navigation, what would cause the Follow and Unfollow buttons to be greyed out?

Even Users in the System Administrator role cannot click the follow button. Org wide permissions have been granted in both the Follow and Post Entities in the Security Roles. The entities that would need to be followed have been added in the Activity Feeds Configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Follow is a record which has a user as one parent record (the "owner" of the follow) and the record being followed as the other.
You would need privileges to "Append To" your own user record and to the record you are trying to follow. This might mean you need BU or Org level rights to "append to" records if you don't own them but want to follow them